# file put contents append before last second line

Tags: php

```
1st line
2nd line
...
//append here
last line
```

I have a php script use file put content append

I need to append between last 2nd line & last line?

anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: File exists and you have to append, or you have full file content and then you want append and save?

Comment: file already exist, and i want to append & save

Comment: Ok, so look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756806/fgets-php-read-last-line?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `file()`, and outputs an array. From there you can determine the second to the last line. Consider this example:

```
$replacement = "Hello World";
$contents = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$size = count($contents);
$contents[$size-2] = $replacement; // point it to the second last line and assign
$temp = implode("\n", $contents);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $temp);
```