# How to read file(bigger) in php from bottom up

Tags: php

How to read files from bottom up in php?Is there something like stream in java which will read file incrementally but just backwards. Because my files can get up to 650 mb.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek/3234857#3234857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has streams. See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php