# Creating a Log Detector: Running Shell Scripts from PHP not working. Processes keep running OR broken pipe

Tags: php, shell, pipe, cat

My aim is to create a log file reader using PHP and Shell scripting. 
I plan to run the script at intervals in order to detect the last time a particular entry shows up in the logfile.

The way it should work is by calling the PHP script which in turn calls a shell command

```
tac logfile.log | grep "what i am looking for" | head -n 1
```

or

```
tac logfile.log | head -n 1
```

What this script will do is:

**in the case of the first script:** scan the log file from the bottom up until it finds what it is looking for and shows me the first line, which is actually the last occurrence of the line in the file.

**in the case of the second script:** scan only the last line and output it. I am NOT trying to tail the file.

So my intention is to scan the file from the end to the last occurence but I need php to do this because PHP can parse the lines it reads from the shell output and parse them easily.

The issue i am trying to resolve is that once I run the script from PHP using the functions shell_exec, exec, backtick operator, system etc. They all keep the PHP script running or output the result and keeps the first part of the shell running (tac logfile.log).

I dont understand why it works perfectly from CLI but runs indefinitely by trying to tac the whole log file when I run the same script from PHP. Ive noticed that tac and cat give this problem. Sometimes it shows the error "Broken pipe".

What should I be doing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pure PHP. Open the the file with fopen, an example how to read a file backwards can be found at [Read a file backwards line by line using fseek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek)
than just break the loop after you found your string you search for.