# php - output last block of text(separated by empty lines) from a text file

Tags: php, output

I have a large text file in this form:

```
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.

This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.

This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
```

etc.
I want to output the last couple of chunks/blocks of text from this file in my website.
I currently use this:

```
$line = '';

$f = fopen('output.log', 'r');
$cursor = -1;

fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
$char = fgetc($f);

/**
 * Trim trailing newline chars of the file
 */
while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}

/**
 * Read until the start of file or first newline char
 */
while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
    /**
     * Prepend the new char
     */
    $line = $char . $line;
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}

echo $line;
```

That shows just the last line. Any thought about this would be awesome! Thanks!
Edit: All blocks are separated by empty lines, the script should print the last few blocks.

Comment: What's your definition of "last chunks of text"? How do you determine which part to use? And why do you work character by character? With `fgets()` you can read entire lines at once.

Comment: look here, might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek

Comment: A chunk of text from this file is determined by n lines of text separated by an empty line, followed by another 'chunk' of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here go:

file.txt

```
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.

This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.

This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
This is a linie of text.
```

process.php:

```
$fileContents = file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$numberOfLines = count($fileContents);

for($i = $numberOfLines-2; $i<$numberOfLines; $i++)
{
    echo $fileContents[$i];
}
```

This will output the last 2 lines of text from the file

Alternatively, use substr to return the last 50 letters of text:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('file.txt');
echo subtr($fileContents, -50, 50);
```

Comment: I like this approach. But it lacks the formatting. Eg: "This is a line of textThis is a line of text" - these two should be on 2 separate lines.

Comment: You can then use: `implode("\n", array(array_slice($fileContents, -2,2));` This will join the array elements by a new line, and only retrieve the last 2 elements. If you want to retrieve the last 3 elements, just replace `-2` with `-3`, and `2` with `3`

Comment: I choose this. Thank you all for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

unless the file is prohibitively large, you could just explode it

```
$allLines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('your/file') );
$endLines = array_slice( $allLines, -2 );
echo implode("\n", $endLines );
```

If you want to match blocks containing any number of lines, you could explode with a double line break "\n\n"

If the whitespace characters aren't reliably uniform, you could use preg_match. e.g.

```
$allBlocks = preg_split( '/[\n\r]\s*[\n\r]/', file_get_contents('your/file'), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
```

Comment: This is the best possible solution, as for me.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file with `file_get_contents()` and the `explode` by double new line, then pick out the last element with `array_pop()`.

Comment: You can use file() to split the contents into an array :)

Comment: @PhilCross `file()` reads the document line by line, he's actually interested in the last block, not indivual lines if I understood OP's request correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I miscommunicated the suggestion, instead of `file_get_contents()` then `explode()`, file() will do both functions for you, you could then just grab the last couple of array elements :)

Comment: All blocks are separated by empty lines, the script should print the last few blocks. I'll update the OP too.

Comment: @PhilCross True, but how will you then know where the blocks begin and end?

Comment: I just want to print the lines of text between empty lines.

Comment: My solution is exactly the one as Tim's, that I what I wanted to state out :)

Comment: Using `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` in the file function will automatically remove empty lines from the text. You can find out the number of lines in the file by using count() on the array :), then just user $file[lineNumber] to get the line, for example, `$fileContents[count($file)]`

Answer (score 0):

For large files this code will work faster than regular expressions .

```
$mystring = file_get_contents('your/file');    
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "\n")
if($pos === false)
    $pos = strrpos($mystring, "\r");
$result = substr($mystring, $pos);
```