# Making array_reverse when using fgets | text file

Tags: php, arrays, explode, fgets, array-reverse

I want to reorder my array from last bottom line to first on the top. I'm trying use array_reverse, but i fail all runs.

Anyone of you, have an idea how i could implement this into my code?
Everything works, but i only need array in reverse

Thanks

*this is my code:*

```
<?php
$f = fopen("list.txt", "r");

while (!feof($f)) { 

$arrM = explode("###",fgets($f));

echo "<p align='center'><b><font color='red' size='6'>" . $arrM[5]. " PLN</font></b><br><b><font size='5'>" . $arrM[3]. "</b></font><br><a target='_blank' href='" . $arrM[1] . "'><img src=" . $arrM[2]. " width='100%' /></a><br><br><br><br></p>";

}

fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: Please add more context.

Comment: Check both answers here https://stackoverflow.com/q/20561480/1207049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Try This**

```
 <?php
$data = [];

$f = fopen("list.txt", "r");

// store all data line by line in a 2D array
while (!feof($f)) { 
    $data[] = explode("###",fgets($f));
}

// reverse your data array
$arrM = array_reverse($data);

// echo data
foreach ($arrM as $row) {
    echo "<p align='center'>
    <b><font color='red' size='6'>" . $row[5]. " PLN</font></b><br>
    <b><font size='5'>" . $row[3]. "</b></font><br>
    <a target='_blank' href='" . $row[1] . "'><img src=" . $row[2]. " width='100%' /></a></p>";
}

fclose($f);  ?>
```

Comment: Ani, you are incredible. You helped me so much!