# How to read and process lines backwards from a file in php

Tags: php

I post this topic because I've tried to solve my problem by checking other posts related to the same problem but I couldn't find the same specific thing.

I'm trying to manage a log file, in which I have a long line, I just want some substring from that line (Which I've already solved by using strtok, that's not the problem), the main problem is about the how to manage the lines.

I need to know if a ID is repeated before, because I want to know if a router hotspot is up.
I need to read from the bottom upwards (reverse order I mean) and take one line, from that line I need to take the time (hour) and find in reverse (upwards) in the lines before while that hour is higher thant the current time minus 2 hours, I mean, I need to know if a hotspot has answered in the last two hours, so I need to take a line and find if that id has been viewed before.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work, it's PHP, hope some can help me, thanks.

```
<?php
// full path to text file
define("TEXT_FILE", "C:\Users\Alvaro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManejaLog\log2.txt");
// number of lines to read from the end of file
define("LINES_COUNT", 500);


function read_file($file, $lines) {
    //global $fsize;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $linecounter = $lines;
    $pos = -2;
    $beginning = false;
    $text = array();
    while ($linecounter > 0) {
        $t = " ";
        while ($t != "\n") {
            if(fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
                $beginning = true; 
                break; 
            }
            $t = fgetc($handle);
            $pos --;
        }
        $linecounter --;
        if ($beginning) {
            rewind($handle);
        }
        // Estoy en una linea
            //Atributos de cada linea (DIA/HORA/NASID).
            $nada = strtok($handle,":");
            $dia = strtok(" ");
            $hora = strtok("-");
            $nada2 = strtok(" ");
            $id = strtok(",");
            $cadena = $dia." ".$hora." ".$id;

            //Hora actual, a la que restamos 2, para comprobar los actualizados hasta 2 horas.
            $now = new DateTime();
            $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $now->modify("-2 hours");
            //Se busca hacia arriba en el fichero mientras que el valor de horascomprobar <= currentline.gethora (pseucodigo)
            $horascomprobar = $now->format('H');

            $date = new DateTime(dia." ".hora);
            $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $horaslinea = $date->format('H');

            while (horascomprobar <= horaslinea) {
                $t = " ";
                while ($t != "\n") {
                    if(fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
                        $beginning = true; 
                        break; 
                    }
                    $t = fgetc($handle);
                    $pos --;
                }
                $linecounter --;
                if ($beginning) {
                    rewind($handle);
                }

                //Estoy en una linea
                    //Atributos de cada linea (DIA/HORA/NASID).
                    $auxnada = strtok($handle,":");
                    $auxdia = strtok(" ");
                    $auxhora = strtok("-");
                    $auxnada2 = strtok(" ");
                    $auxid = strtok(",");
                    $datelinea = new DateTime(auxdia." ".auxhora);
                    $datelinea->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $horaslinea = $datelinea->format('H');
                    if(strnatcasecmp ($id, $auxid)) {
                        echo $cadena;
                    }
                //
                if ($beginning) break;
            }
        //
        //$text[$lines-$linecounter-1] = fgets($handle);
        if ($beginning) break;
    }
    fclose ($handle);
    return array_reverse($text);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Here is a good answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3234644/1011527

Comment: Yeah, it's a good answer but in my case I need to open the file from the bottom, read the last line, and compare with all of the lines above that, then, take the line before, and do the same...
The problem is about comparing with the lines above, I mean, There's no problem in reading in reverse order, the main problem is read the lines before that line and then continue doing the same backwards.