# php Read csv file in reverse

Tags: php

I have this php script that reads the csv file, I would like it to start reading from the last line, basically the other way around.

```
<?php
$f = fopen("./data/data-esp8266-$idluf-$currentdata.csv", "r");
        fgets($f);
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
       
        $row = $line[0];  // Dobbiamo ottenere la riga effettiva (è il primo elemento in un array di 1 elemento)
        $cells = explode(";",$row);
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
             echo "<td><a style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;' class='tooltip' data-tool=' $cell'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</a></td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: I've removed the duplicate close as using the "reverse fseek()" method will not work reliably for CSV unless you are also parsing the CSV in reverse as well. At best it will work in the naive case that the CSV data itself will _never_ contain unescaped line breaks, which is not guaranteed by the format.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Or you can use loop with for:

```
<?php
$lines = file("./data/data-esp8266-$idluf-$currentdata.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Loop through the lines array in reverse
for ($i = count($lines)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $row = $lines[$i];
    //$cells = explode(";", $row); // We can use the function explode() only if ; is not inside a quoted string
    //$cells = preg_split('/;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $row); // Otherwise, we can use a regular expression (for big files it's more faster than str_getcsv)
    $cells = str_getcsv( $row,  ";", "\"", "\\" ); // Also, we can use the function str_getcsv
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        // $cell = trim($cell, "\""); // Only if we use regular expressions
        echo "<td><a style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;' class='tooltip' data-tool=' $cell'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</a></td>\n";

    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

This method should be faster than the other way based on the function array_reverse()

Comment: Thank you so much for the effective solution...

Comment: The script works perfectly, but what if I want to delete the first empty field?

Comment: I corrected the code. Please, check now)

Comment: `$cells = explode(";", $row);` is very bad way to read CSV. What if `;` is _inside_ quoted string and not as separator?

Comment: You are right. djroby19 used the function explode(), so I decided it is not important. But for solving this problem, I think we should use regular expressions like: `$cells = preg_split('/;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $row);` and then trim the apostrophes `$cell = trim($cell, "\"");`

Comment: @OlehKosarenko You should use `str_getcsv` to parse single string line as CSV, not some regexes or other stuff

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's a good idea. But using regular expressions will be a little faster (for very big files). Anyway, thank you for discussing this.

Comment: It is not "a little" but actually was 40 times faster with explode when i checked last time. Still you should use the dedicated function to parse CSV of unknown format. Least you should casually strip quotes that may be present in the value. I wish developers would learn someday not to meddle with special formats using such brute force.

Comment: Yes, yes, I mean faster. I agree with you about special formats. I replaced it in my main answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the file you're reading were a "simple" file with nothing but line breaks as delimiters, then reading it backwards would be fairly simple. However, CSV is a more complex format with field and row delimiters, enclosures [quotes], and escapes. You could encounter data such as:

```csv
id,name,value
1,foo,"hello world"
2,bar,"hello 
world"
3, baz,"""hello 
world"""
```

Which is perfectly valid CSV, but would break most solutions currently proposed in this thread to read the data backwards, as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek) which this question was briefly marked as duplicate of.

The most reliable way to do this would be to read the file *forwards* first, and then use that information to read it in reverse. The simple version is to just stuff everything into an array and then read that backwards, eg:

```php
$f = fopen("./data/data-esp8266-$idluf-$currentdata.csv", "r");
fgets($f);

$lines = [];
while (($lines[] = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {}

for( $i=count($lines)-1; $i>=0; --$i ) {
    $line = lines[$i];
    $row = $line[0];  // Dobbiamo ottenere la riga effettiva (è il primo elemento in un array di 1 elemento)
    $cells = explode(";",$row);
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        echo "<td><a style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;' class='tooltip' data-tool=' $cell'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</a></td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
```

but if you're processing a large file you may run into memory constraints trying to store all that data.

An alternative would be to read the file forward once first, but only store the offsets in the file for the beginning of the records, and then use those offsets to iterate again in reverse.

```php
function csv_reverse($handle, ...$csv_options) {
    $offsets = [];
    do {
        $offsets[] = ftell($handle);
    } while($row = fgetcsv($handle, ...$csv_options));
    array_pop($offsets); // last offset is EOF
    
    for( $i=count($offsets)-1; $i>=0; --$i ) {
        fseek($handle, $offsets[$i]);
        yield fgetcsv($handle, ...$csv_options);
    }
}

$f = fopen("./data/data-esp8266-$idluf-$currentdata.csv", "r");
fgets($f); // assuming that this discards the header row

$lines = [];
while (($lines[] = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {}

foreach( csv_reverse($f) as $line ) {
    // same as above
}
fclose($f);
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/0sc8q

There is a tradeoff here, in that the file must be traversed twice, but that's going to have to be a necessary evil if there is a memory constraint.

All this said, the *better* option would be to have this data in a database, if possible, which can trivially re-order the data for you on the fly. This code is already kinda-sorta reimplementing DB-related functionality, but worse.

**Edit, because @Your-Common-Sense won't stop bothering me about this.**

Here is a first-pass buffered reverse CSV iterator that respects quotes, and escaped quotes [probably] but probably has other less-common edge-case issues.

```php
define('DEBUG', false);

function chunk_read_reverse($handle, $bufsz=4096) {
    fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    do{
        $cur = ftell($handle);
        if( $cur - $bufsz <= 0 ) {
            if( $cur == 0 ) { return; }
            fseek($handle, 0);
            yield fread($handle, $cur);
            return;
        } else {
            fseek($handle, -1 * $bufsz, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        $buffer = fread($handle, $bufsz);
        yield $buffer;
        fseek($handle, -1 * $bufsz, SEEK_CUR);
    } while(true);
}

function csv_reverse_iterate($handle, ...$csv_options) {
    $quote   = $csv_options[1] ?? '"';
    $endl    = "\n";
    $buffer  = '';
    $end     = 0;
    $q_count = 0;
    foreach(chunk_read_reverse($handle) as $chunk) {
        $buffer = $chunk . $buffer;
        $buflen = strlen($buffer);
        if(DEBUG){printf("bufflen: %4d, end: %4d\n", $buflen, $end);}
        for( $i=strlen($chunk)-1; $i>=0; --$i ) {
            $c = $buffer[$i];
            if(DEBUG){printf("i: %3d, e: %3d, c: %1s, x: %s, q: %d\n", $i, $end, trim($c), bin2hex($c), $q_count);}
            if( $c === $quote ) {
                ++$q_count;
            }
            else if( $c === $endl && $q_count % 2 == 0 ) {
                yield str_getcsv(substr($buffer, $i+1, ($buflen-$end)-($i+1)), ...$csv_options);
                $end = $buflen - $i;
            }
        }
        $buffer = substr($buffer, 0, $buflen-$end);
        $end = 0;
    }
    yield str_getcsv($buffer, ...$csv_options);
}

$csv = <<<_E_
id,name,value
1,foo,"hello world"
2,bar,"hello 
world"
3, baz,"""hello 
world"""
_E_;

$in = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');
fwrite($in, $csv);
rewind($in);

foreach( csv_reverse_iterate($in) as $row ) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

I don't necessarily recommend using this, as it only cares about quotes and line breaks and does not account for other potential format quirks. But if you want to be pedantic like @Your-Common-Sense and save a questionably-significant amount of processing time, then you can use this slightly-worse-but-maybe-slightly-faster code.

**Let me reiterate:** If you need to do this enough that a few extra milliseconds makes a difference, then you should almost certainly be using a database, or database-like solution, and not CSV/flat files. This code was written purely out of spite.

Comment: fgetcsv is awfully slow alone, and you are running it twice

Comment: A native solution would be 2 times faster, if implements a buffer-based backward reading principle featured in a *former duplicate*

Comment: Yes, and it would _still_ break on a line break inside of a field. If you know of a way to parse CSV faster and/or backwards go ahead and add a better answer.

Comment: Not sure what makes you think it would break. Probably you didn't bother to check how it actually works

Comment: Oh yes, it works _flawlessly_. https://3v4l.org/k5ftF

Comment: I assume you took this code from the accepted answer. But from experience, we can tell that top voted answer is not necessarily the best/useful one.

Comment: They are all various flavors of "iterate in reverse by line breaks" which will _all still break_ in this case because they're not format-aware. At this point either post working code, or drop it.

Comment: it's not a "reverse by line breaks" which is quite dumb, because reads by one byte at a time. But, like I said, a smart solution utilizing a buffer-based backward reading principle when data for parsing is read by chunks

Comment: Yes, that is a slightly different way to phrase the wrong answer. Where code?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Don't worry about the code. I posted it for you already.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you just need to read the file backwards line by line
As shown here
[Read a file backwards line by line using fseek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234580/read-a-file-backwards-line-by-line-using-fseek)

If you're willing to load the whole file into memory you can use `file_get_contents(<path>);` , split the file by line end character and read the resulting array from len back down to 1

Comment: If you're willing to read the whole thing into memory you might as well read it normally, store the data in an array, and iterate the array in reverse. Also, making suggestions and/or linking to other resources does not qualify as an answer.

Answer (score -3):

If file is relatively small, you can read whole file into memory using [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), than reverse it and loop:

```php
$csvLines = file("./data/data-esp8266-{$idluf}-{$currentdata}.csv",  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$csvLines = array_reverse($csvLines);

foreach ($csvLines as $csvLine) {
    $line = str_getcsv($csvLine);

    /* ... */
}
```